# Nativescript RadListView: How to change background color programmatically on selected item?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, radlistview

Doing this programmatically in the code behind (not binding to XML), everything works except my background color does not show when the item is selected. No errors and my images show up fine. What's messed up in my code? (Thanks!)

I'm running `{N} CLI    "tns-android":"version": "3.4.2", "nativescript-ui-listview": "3.5.1"`.

```
<GridLayout columns="auto, *">
    <StackLayout col="0" id="containers">
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout col="1" id="notes">
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>


function setContainers() {
    myCntnrPics.forEach(function (element) { // Need to it in ObservableArray
        pathToCntnrBitmapsArray.push(element);
    });

    let radListLeft = new listview.RadListView();
    // iOS NEEDS height set
    radListLeft.height = 2000;
    radListLeft.items = pathToCntnrBitmapsArray;
    let gridLayout = new listview.ListViewGridLayout();
    gridLayout.scrollDirection = "Vertical";
    radListLeft.selectionBehavior = "Press";
    radListLeft.itemSelected = "selected";
    radListLeft.on("itemSelected", function (ListViewEventData) {
        const item = pathToCntnrBitmapsArray.getItem(args.index);
        item.selected = true;
        console.log("itemSelected is true -----"); // This does not show up
    });
    radListLeft.on("itemTap", function (element){
        var selectedItemPath = pathToCntnrBitmapsArray.getItem(element.index).toString();
        console.log("on itemTap selectedItemPath: " + selectedItemPath); // shows correctly
    });
    if (application.android) {
        // Android needs H & W
        radListLeft.itemTemplate = "<StackLayout backgroundColor='{{ selected ? 'red' : 'white'}}'><Image src='{{ $value }}' height='123' width='123' loadMode='async' class='items'/></StackLayout>";
    } else if (application.ios) {
        radListLeft.itemTemplate = "<StackLayout backgroundColor='{{ selected ? 'red' : 'white'}}'><Image src='{{ $value }}' class='items'/></StackLayout>";
        gridLayout.itemHeight = 123;
        gridLayout.itemWidth = 123;
    }
    gridLayout.spanCount = 1;
    radListLeft.listViewLayout = gridLayout;
    let myContainers = page.getViewById("containers");
    myContainers.removeChildren();
    myContainers.addChild(radListLeft);
}
```

Comment: try style.backgroundColor='{{ selected ? 'red' : 'white'}}'

Comment: In your `itemSelected` event you are passing `ListViewEventData` but trying to access `args.index`. You might want to fix that. Also may I know what you have in your `pathToCntnrBitmapsArray`. It must be an array of Observable so you can dynamically toggle property in it (like selected) to bind backgroundColor. Another issue here is that you are setting selected to true but it's never set back to false anywhere?

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses! I’m new to {N}, so I’m sorry I’m a little dense with how it all works. The only code samples I’ve found for RadListView on selection state are all done by binding to the XML and in this project I have to do it by code behind. Doing my best on my limited understanding to translate the sample code from Telerik [link](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/How-To/selection-states) and I need a little help to get the picture on how it’s supposed to work.

Comment: I have an “itemTap” event in my sample code because I how to use it, but do I even need both if I’m using the “itemSelected” event? All I want to do is when the item is tapped/selected in the observable array change its background color for that item, and then I’ll update the UI with notes that goes with that selected item. Can I even do this '<StackLayout backgroundColor='{{ selected ? 'red' : 'white'}}'>' or should it be '<StackLayout backgroundColor='{{ $value ? 'red' : 'white'}}'>' ? Where would I initialize “selected” to false in the code behind?